# Prevent form to display default values when validation fails codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function edit_profile(){

        $logged_in_user = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['images_url'] = $this->config->item('images_url');
        $data['cdn_url'] = $this->config->item('cdn_url');
        $data['reminder'] = $this->config->item('reminder');
        $data['current_module'] = "ess";
        $data['user_details'] = $this->ess->get_user_details($logged_in_user['user_id']);
        $this->load->view("header", $data);
        $this->load->view("leftbar", $data);
        $this->load->view("ess/ess_edit_profile");
        $this->load->view("footer", $data);

           if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $post_data = $this->input->post();
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name','Full Name','required|trim|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|trim|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('blood_group','Blood Group','max_length[2]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Phone','required|trim|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('address','Address','required|xss_clean|max_length[100]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('designation','Designation','required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emergency_name','Emergency Name','required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('emergency_number','Emergency Number','required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('next_of_kin','Next of Kin','trim|xss_clean');

            if($this->form_validation->run() === true){
                // update data
            } else {
                $this->load->view("ess/ess_edit_profile");
            }



}
}
```

Above is the function of my controller that loads a edit profile view with database populated values in input fields. Now when the form get submitted after doing editing it goes to validation process in `edit_profile()` function. I am deliberately running false the validation function for checking purpose. Now if the validation runs === false i loaded the `ess_edit_profile` view again but the validation messages are not appearing. Also the form fields are getting populated with default values which i've set via `set_value()` function

Below is how i am showing form fields with database data

```
 <td>
                    <label for="full_name">Full Name</label>
                    <input style="width: 300px;" type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" value="<?php echo set_value('full_name',$user_details[0]->ui_full_name); ?>" />
                    <?php echo form_error('full_name', '<span class="alert">', '</span>'); ?>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this remove else part then try

```
  if($this->form_validation->run() === true){
                // update data
            } 
   $this->load->view("ess/ess_edit_profile");
```

Comment: What's different in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `set_value` function to set element values

Like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value("name", $database_name)?>"/>
```

In Controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Edit name','trim|xss_clean|required');
```

If the value not required then also set validation rules `trim`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Edit name','trim');
```

Comment: @Grish i've updated my question. I am already doing this kindly check